# Publish Android and IOS application

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Hello does anyone know if i can publish application where is only login screen? I have a fit center which want to create application only for their members, so that means that google play testers or ios testers or anyone else who is not a member of that fit center cannot log in. Only members will obtain login into their e-mails. Thank you

Comment: I highly doubt you will pass iOS review if your app is just a login screen, also iOS you need to supply a valid login credentials for their testers to review your app. Android they don't really manually review your app so in theory you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Apple would probably reject the app if they can not verify what the app does and is as per their requirements.This is how I go for such use cases:

- Create a test account for apple testers in DB.
- Share the credentials while submitting the app. So that they can test the app functionalities by logging in.
- Once the app is approved and on app store. Disable or delete that account from the database so it does not effect any thing.

Hope it helps.